# What does a passenger aircraft galley ('kitchen') look like?

Tags: airline-operations

What equipment is installed in passenger aircraft for catering the passenger?

Comment: [BEA galleys](http://beaerospace.com/products/galley-systems/galleys/) - [A321](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JE878yH5jfg) - More [Galleys on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=galley)

Comment: My recommendation would be to check out the market leader, [Sell GmbH in Herborn](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sell_GmbH), Germany. Their [website](http://www.zodiacaerospace.com/en/zodiac-galleys) is hosted by their French owners.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[image: Lufthansa A380]

An aircraft Kitchen is known as the **Galley** and the picture is from a Lufthansa A380.

Some equipment you will see here are:

- **Food Oven**, the door with a black knob in the middle of the picture.
- **Coffee Machine**, with the pot, in the right side of the picture.
- **Large Trolleys**, filled with food and/or drinks, on the floor. Weight about 25kg empty.
- **Trash Bin**, the darker grey unit on the right on the floor. Wheeled off like everything else. Some have proper trash electric trash compactors as well in trolley format.
- **Fuse Panel**, located in the middle along the top row. There is in general a fair bit of power going into this area.
- **Smaller Storage Containers**, that can handle drinks or bottles for instance.
- **General Storage Space**: The galley also provides a bit of space for anything from the children's toys and newspapers to emergency equipment. You can see some compartments for this in the upper-left corner and a symbol that a smoke hood is stored in one of them.

### Quick design comment:

Aircraft galleys are hotspots for corrosion due to the liquid in the area and is the cause for particular attention during maintenance. Most aircraft galleys are generally very similar in design.

> Galley equipment comes in 2 basic universal standards - namely ATLAS and KSSU. These have their origins in legacy maintenance resource pools (ATLAS = Alitalia, TAP, Lufthansa, Air France, Sabena and KSSU = KLM, Swissair, SAS, UTA) and have subsequently developed into industry standards to enable modular equipment interchange.

These standards for instance specify the height, width and depth of trolleys. I gather that ATLAS standard is more prevalent (80% of galleys by one source) but both exist. Other ideas and concepts have popped up but since changing the stuff is very expensive there's not been a real push for it. I think I've also read that the original standard was pretty well thought through.

Naturally, this is a long-distance galley that will serve usually two meals. Equipment and size are scaled to the needs of the airline and can vary greatly between operators.

Comment: Further: About 80% of airline galleys are based on the ATLAS standard which defines the shape of the trays and trolleys used for loading food. This imposes the dimensions of the modular elements of the galley. Other standards include KSSU, ARINC and SPICE (based on ATLAS trays).

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Remember reading about that, will add a bit on it :)

Comment: "The grey unit" had me puzzled for a second, since they *all* look rather gray to me. :)

Comment: Not all grey. Some of the parts/panels - edges on the trolleys, oven door - appear to me to have a sort of an anodized (slightly gold-ish) color.

Comment: I've noticed on some flights they block the cockpit doors with a trolley from the galley. Anyone know what protocol that is? Other times I see them just blocking it with their bodies. Why the difference?